# Is there a way to dynamically load JS chunks without prior knowledge of them?

Tags: webpack

I am trying to modularize a web app, here are some highlights:

- there is a container app (main JS bundle, loaded by the webpage) with a router
- routes data is being fetched dynamically (or embedded into the HTML)
- routes are built dynamically based on this data
- each route is rendered by a dynamically fetched JS chunk, url to fetch should be taken from the routes data

So my question is how can I achieve this with webpack? I am aware of dynamic `import()` feature, but it requires a module path which I don't have as it should be defined later and it should be different for every route. I am thinking about writing a plugin to override chunk fetching internals provided by webpack itself but maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I've actually been through this pain myself. Webpack and Browserify *can* do it but I'm not a massive fan of the way it does it. You are indeed correct - you need to know in advance what can/needs to be be loaded.

Im using Go and GopherJS in my current setup but my previous one used NodeJS, [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) and [RollupJS](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en) and I still use the SystemJS and RollupJS components to this day.

#### Core Bundle

For bundling you sort of have to think ahead, personally I bundle the major components and generally call it core.bundle.js. Within my projects I put all the client side stuff in its own jslib folder:

[Standard Project Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii6s1.png)

I use TypeScript so in ./src/index.ts I reference my main libs..:

```
//@ts-ignore
import * as jquery from "jquery";
import * as popper from "popper.js"
import * as bootstrap from "../vendor/bootstrap/index.js"
import * as backbone from "backbone"
import * as lodash from "lodash"

//@ts-ignore
window.jquery = window.jQuery = window.$ = jquery;
//@ts-ignore
window.popper = popper;
//@ts-ignore
window.bootstrap = bootstrap;
//@ts-ignore
window.Backbone = backbone;
//@ts-ignore
window._ = window.lodash = lodash;
```

Apologies about the verbosity but GopherJS can be funny about needing things in certain places - but at least everything is setup on the window object that needs to be there.

Then we have our dynamic loader in the same file:

```
import * as SystemJS from 'systemjs';
import * as Promise from "bluebird";

export class DynamicModuleManager {

  constructor() {
    //load up the main package and initialise SystemJS for use

    SystemJS.config({
      baseURL: '/_pkg', //your dynamic requires will use this folder for the root
      meta: { '*': { scriptLoad: true } }
    });
  }

  public init() {
    //Register the modules you have already loaded!

    //@ts-ignore
    SystemJS.set('lodash', SystemJS.newModule({
      //@ts-ignore
      "default": window.lodash
    }));
    //@ts-ignore
    SystemJS.set('jquery', SystemJS.newModule({
      //@ts-ignore
      "default": window.$
    }));

    //Optionally add some shim/fake modules to allow NodeJS stuff to be used if needed

    //@ts-ignore
      SystemJS.set('child_process', SystemJS.newModule({
      ChildProcess: {}
    }));
  }

  public import(moduleId:string) {
    return SystemJS.import(moduleId).then((m) => {

      console.log(`Loading Module: ${moduleId}`);

      //m is the module object just like you had "required" it
      return m

    });
  }

}
```

If you use typescript my tsconfig is like this for the core bundle:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "baseUrl": "./src/",
    "outDir": "./build/",
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "./node_modules/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

And then the rollup config is like this:

```
// rollup.config.js
import builtins from 'rollup-plugin-node-builtins';
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import json from 'rollup-plugin-json';

export default {
  input: './build/index.js',
  output: {
    file: '../assets/js/core.bundle.js',
    format: 'cjs'
  },
  name: 'core_bundle',
  plugins: [
    json(),
    builtins(),
    nodeResolve(),
    commonjs(),
  ]
}
```

I dont use the rollup-typescript plugin because it caused me issue so its a 3 stage build:

```
$ cd ~/your_web_project/jslib

$ npm init && npm install --save jquery... [OTHER DEPS] 
## When you clone just make sure to do npm install

$ tsc -p tsconfig.json 
## if you are running typescript remember to install globally

$ rollup -c
## again install globally
```

Now you will have ~/your_web_project/assets/js/core.bundle.js

#### Sub Modules

So now you can build other modules/chunks. For the above config you need to have them in a dir that is served by your favourite server, or from a route within node for example: GET /_pkg/:module_name -> ~/your_web_project/resources/_pkg/:module_name.js

On your modules all you need to do is setup another jslib folder, much the same but this time tell rollupjs about your external packages...

[Dynamically Loadable VSCode/Monaco Environment for Golang Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7jd5.png)

```
// rollup.config.js
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import json from 'rollup-plugin-json';
import alias from 'rollup-plugin-alias';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import * as filepath from "path"


//export an array of webpack configs for multiple modules..
export default [
  {
    input: './build/index.js',
    external : ["lodash", "jquery"], //make sure to make the module aware of anything external otherwise it will get bundled!
    output: {
      file: '../resources/devide.go.js',
      format: 'cjs',
    },
    plugins: [
      nodeResolve({
        module: true,
        jsnext: true,
        extensions: [ '.js', '.json' ]
      }),
      commonjs(),
      alias({
        'golangcli': filepath.resolve(__dirname, 'build/golangcli/client'),
        'vscode': require.resolve('monaco-languageclient/lib/vscode-compatibility')
      }),
      json(),
      postcss({
        plugins: [] //you can even embed CSS in your sources and have it load here...
      }),
      babel({
        "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
        "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
      })
    ]
  }
];
```

The above example is a bit extreme as I use Typescript and Babel before bundling with Rollup.

The tsconfig needs some slight changes too:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "baseUrl": "./src/",
    "outDir": "./build/",
    "inlineSourceMap": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "./node_modules/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

This will force proper tree shaking when the source gets to rollup and ensure only what is actually needed is imported. Important when the Monaco payload is over 10MB!

Rollup is an excellent bit of kit, I even use it to rollup entire server side codebases so they can be copied about and run dependencies and all with no issues (as long as you have the node binary) and it works very nicely with the Golang, Buffalo, GopherJS setup I have.

#### TL;DR

The above issue is something I have wrestled with for a long time and felt it was worthy of my first ever Answer on SO. No doubt there are holes in the above solution but hopefully it inspires someone!